# Find the value(s) of $\alpha$ in matrix $A$ such that the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda = 4$ is $2$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The problem is simple. Find the value(s) of $\alpha$ in matrix $A$ such that the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda = 4$ is $2$.

However, $A$ is a $4 \times 4$ matrix, meaning taking the determinant by hand is a pretty long processe. Is that simply what you have to do, and then work out what $\alpha$ is from the context.

Or is there a shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

The geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue cannot (necessarily) be detected from the characteristic polynomial $\det(\lambda I - A)$ so it is not clear how calculating a determinant will help. Instead, if $\lambda = 4$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with geometric multiplicity $2$ then you must have $\mathrm{rank} (A - 4I) = 4 - 2 = 2$. Thus, you need to find $\alpha$ such that $\mathrm{rank} (A(\alpha) - 4I) = 2$ which can be done using elementary row or column operations.